# Is there an equivalant of 'as' for with in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the knockout.js `foreach` you can use the `as` parameter to save a value into the context as an alias, so you can use it somewhere far deeper in the binding. See the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'category' }">
</ul>
```

Is there an equivalant for with? Something like: `with: { data: item, as: 'category' }`?

Or is there a better way to do this?

What I'd like to prevent:

- using the relative way with `$parent.$parent` etc
- putting this in the view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is not. You can see how `as` is implemented in the [`foreach` binding's source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/v3.3.0/src/binding/defaultBindings/foreach.js) and compare it to the [source of the `with` binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/v3.3.0/src/binding/defaultBindings/ifIfnotWith.js) which has nothing of the sort.

You haven't quite provided a full repro of your scenario, so it's rather hard to suggest pragmatic, concrete alternatives to `$parent.$parent`. The main one you've already mentioned yourself (as not wanting to use), which is to do this in the View Models. I will argue that in most cases this *is* in fact the preferred way to do things: relationships between classes / view models / constructor functions is best encoded in the JavaScript code itself. Not in the least because that would make it unit testable.

The only alternative you have would be to start from `$root` and work your way down. For example, supposing this nesting:

```
var vm = { planet: { name: 'earth', country: { name: 'UK', city: { name: 'London' } } } };
```

Then at the deepest nesting you have two alternatives:

- `$parent.$parent.name`
- `$root.planet.name`

But again: pretty hard to suggest actual alternatives without an actual repro.

Comment: Great answer! I'm not sure yet what the way to go is. Maybe I do have to fix this all within the viewmodel, still trying to figure out the best practices. I recently discovered the `as` and pretty happy how sometimes it makes stuff a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen has stated, there's not an `as` option for the `with` binding. But you can use the `foreach` binding to bind a single item:

```
foreach: { data: item, as: 'category' }
```

If you know that `item` won't ever be null, you can use this simple custom binding to do what you want:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.with2 = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var innerContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(
            function () { return valueAccessor()['data']; },
            valueAccessor()['as']);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```